# VBA excel: update rowsource for combobox control by resizing range

Tags: excel, combobox, resize, range, vba

I am trying to make an VBA update rowsource routine for a series of 3 combobox controls in a userform.
The three comboboxes all reside in a frame named "frm1"
The rowsource of the comboboxes are three seperate columns in a worksheet.
The worksheet are named "options" and **the top cell in each of the three colums holding the rowsources are given the same name as the combobox that refers to it**.
The idea is that i can write in extra rows in the rowsource for any of the comboboxes (simply by typing it into the right column of the worksheet) and then run the routine and thereby automatically expand the rowsource selection for the combobox in question.

However, running the script (by calling it from an UserForm_Activate() routine) gives me "runtime-error '13': Type mismatch"

Can any of you help me out?

```
Private Sub UpdateCB()

    Dim j As Control
    Dim i As Integer

        For Each j In frm1.Controls

            i = 1

            Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("options").Range(j.Name).Offset(i, 0).Value = ""

                i = i + 1

            Loop

            j.RowSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("options").Range(j.Name).Resize(i)

        Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `Dim j As MSForms.Control` - assuming you have nothing but comboboxes on the form.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Hi Rory...thx for your suggestion, but i doesnt change anything

Comment: Hi Simon..the error is on the j.rowsource = ...line

Comment: .`j.rowsource` expect `range.address` not `range.value` or `range reference` which you have now. So, add `.address` at the end of problem line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComboBox.rowsource` expect `range.address` not `range.value` or range reference which you have now. So, add `.address property` at the end of problem line in this way:

```
j.RowSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("options").Range(j.Name).Resize(i).address
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the .tag property to store the column number:

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()
  with thisworkbook.sheets("options")
    combobox1.list=.columns(val(combobox1.tag)).specialcells(2).value
    combobox2.list=.columns(val(combobox2.tag)).specialcells(2).value
    combobox3.list=.columns(val(combobox3.tag)).specialcells(2).value
  end with
end sub
```